# Are non-winning logos from the Stack Overflow logo design contest free to use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, logo

I went through the submissions to Stack Overflow's [99designs logo contest](http://99designs.com/contests/6774) and noticed that some of the non-winning logos were very good. Can I use some of them on my website? If so, are they free to use, or would I have to pay to use them?

Comment: should be contacting the authors/artists of those logos!

Comment: Who would want any of those - no freehand circles, no unicorns, no waffles or bunnies?  Blech!  Clearly we'd get better logos if we re-ran the contest now.  :-p

Comment: One of the problems with spec work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**: Read the 99designs faq on ["Who owns what, and when?"](http://99designs.com/help/who-owns-what-and-when). The people who designed the logos still own the copyright (except for the winner which is now owned by SO), so the only way you could use them would be to track down the individual creators & negotiate directly with them.

Comment: @Alconja thanks man i will definitely talk with them...

Answer (score -6):

Ya! Go sell them! Make money off of the poor people that made them!

Seriously though, would you like someone using your work without permission?

And what could you possibly need them for?

Comment: @George i wont use them if they are not permitted to use it.... People do have ethics understand that first....