# I just found the StackOverflow logo contest on 99designs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fun

http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774

In case you haven't see this.  I thought it was interesting to see all of the entries that could have ended up being the main logo for StackOverflow.

Comment: I believe this is just for nostalgia sake.

Comment: @voyager: I think the "and" is "and he thought it was interesting and worth sharing for those who hadn't seen it previously." I thought the logo designs were interesting as well.

Comment: how did you type less than 15 letters?

Comment: @Jon - he's a ninja. Don't ask.

Comment: ^-- That means I have no comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it free to use other logos of "stackoverflow design contest"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48221/is-it-free-to-use-other-logos-of-stackoverflow-design-contest). I know that it's not an exact dupe, but close enough.

Comment: @voyager I thought it was interesting, so I thought I'd share it with those who also might find it interesting, that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's also on the blog.. not exactly top secret.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/

other 2 site contests:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/logo-contest-winner-for-superusercom/

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/logo-contest-winner-for-serverfaultcom/

Comment: oh, cool... I didn't see it on the blog.  Not trying to expose a secret, I thought it was cool when I stumbled on it the other day and I thought that someone else might also.